# What is different between "<%=TITLE %> " and "${TITLE} " in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP page,I use `<%=TITLE %>` to show the page title, sometimes it is ok.But sometimes the page show that can not cpmplie the code `<%=TITLE %>`.
So I change the code to `${TITLE}`，and it is OK.What is different between `<%=TITLE %>`  and `${TITLE}` in jsp?

Here is my page code:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://"
        + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
        + path + "/"; 
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<base href="<%=basePath%>">
<title><%=TITLE %></title>
<meta name="description" content="${DESCRIPTION}">
<meta name="keyword" content="${KEYWORD}">
</head>
```

I define them in the controller:

```
    ModelAndView mv = this.getModelAndView();
     mv.addObject("DESCRIPTION","MYDESCRIPTION"));
        mv.addObject("KEYWORD","MYKEYWORD");
        mv.addObject("TITLE","MYTITLE");
       return mv;
```

Comment: One's a scriptlet. One's JSP EL. They get their data from different places.

Comment: There isn't any variable TITLE defined in your code the error is correct! define your  variable TITLE according to your logic then try to see if error is resolved?

Comment: I define all of them in the conroller.And return them in the page

Comment: show us your controller code please.

Comment: When You use `${TITLE} ` do you get any errors?

Comment: @ArshadAli,not get any errors when using `${TITLE}`,but get errors in `<%=TITLE %>`

Comment: See my Update and please Have a serious look on __NOTE__!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Answer according to context of your Question
>
> *What is different between “<%=TITLE %> ” and “${TITLE} ” in jsp?*

Since most of the times we print dynamic data in JSP page using out.print() method, there is a shortcut to do this through JSP Expressions. JSP Expression starts with <%= and ends with %>.

```
<% out.print(TITLE); %>
```

above statement is called scriptlet can be written using JSP Expression as

```
<%= TITLE %>
```

We can use scriptlets and JSP expressions to retrieve attributes and parameters in JSP with java code and use it for view purpose. But for web designers, java code is hard to understand and that’s why JSP Specs 2.0 introduced Expression Language (EL) through which we can get attributes and parameters easily using HTML like tags.

Expression language syntax is

```
 ${TITLE}
```

and we can use EL implicit objects and EL operators to retrieve the attributes from different scopes and use them in JSP page.

### UPDATE

> According to your controller related query

I say to write like this

```
<title><%=request.getAttribute("TITLE"); %></title>
```

because it's stored as a request attribute.

> **NOTE**
>
> Scriptlets are discouraged since JSP 2.0 which was released almost a decade(!) ago. So Please use Expression Language (EL).

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: TITLE cannot be resolved to a variable.   <title><%= TITLE %> </title>

Comment: If I user `<title><%= "TITLE" %> </title>`,The title will be "TITLE",it is the variable name,not the variable value.

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
 pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%
 String path = request.getContextPath();
 String basePath = request.getScheme() + "://"
   + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort()
   + path + "/";
   
%>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<base href="<%=basePath%>">
  <title>${TITLE}</title>
<meta name="description" content="${DESCRIPTION}">
<meta name="keyword" content="${KEYWORD}"> 
</head>

Comment: @ Arshad Ali,did I left some import things?

Comment: Oops, don't paste your code in comments, edit your Question and paste there instead, so that it could be clear for reading.

Comment: @flower instead of posting your code in comments on this answer, please edit your question instead. Code in comments is very hard to read, if you instead put it in your question it can be properly formatted, and moreover, your question becomes more clear if other people want to look at it and provide an answer.

Comment: @flower there isn't any variable TITLE defined in your code the error is correct! define your  variable TITLE according to your logic then try to see if error is resolved?